# Spring Security не показывает картинки для анонимного пользователя

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

Пользуюсь Spring Security и Thymeleaf. Spring Security скрывает картинки из папки `resources/static/images` если пользователь не авторизован, при этом сам блок виден. Как сделать, чтобы картинки были доступны для всех?

```
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">

        <h2>Our customers</h2>

        <div class="col-xs-3" >
            <div class="well">
                <img th:src="@{/images/pic1.jpg}" width="75" height="75" class="img-circle"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="well">
                <img th:src="@{/images/pic2.jpg}" width="75" height="75" class="img-circle"/>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Spring Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/images").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для проверки совпадения URL с шаблоном `antMatchers()` Spring использует [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html). Правильный шаблон, в который попадут все файлы в `/images` - это `/images/*`. Чтобы не гадать, шаблон всегда лучше проверить, написав простой юнит-тест:

```
@Test
public void testPathMatcher() {
    final AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    assertTrue(pathMatcher.match("/images/*", "/images/picture.png"));
}
```

Много дополнительных примеров шаблонов можно посмотреть в [тестах Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcherTests.java).

---

Если говорить о статических ресурсах, то они обычно игнорируются, а не на назначаются правам доступа, как делаете вы. Вот пример:

**WEB-INF**

```
└───WEB-INF
    ├───fonts
    ├───images
    ├───scripts
    ├───styles
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/fonts/");
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
            .antMatchers("/styles/**")
            .antMatchers("/images/**")
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //... настройка security
    }

}
```

Соответствующий шаблон включает каталог, и все вложенные подкаталоги.